# Detect mouseover in an HTML dropdown menu

Tags: html, drop-down-menu, onmouseover

Here, I'm trying to display an alert message when a dropdown menu is moused over, but [I can't get it to work](http://jsbin.com/ihilak/1/edit) using `onmouseover`. Is it possible to detect a mouseover of an element in a dropdown list?

```
<select>
  <option value="Item1" onmouseover = "alert('Item1 is moused over!')">item1</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Works in latest Firefox, but not Chrome or IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/Z8azX/

Comment: @KevinBoucher I'm trying to find a solution that would work in all browsers.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902405/onmousemove-doesnt-fire-over-option-element-in-chrome

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10240205/jquery-hover-event-doesnt-work-with-select-option-tag-in-google-chrome

Comment: I think you are missing a ; after your alert command