# Mouse Listeners and select option in JavaScript. mouseover eventListener does not work with <option> of <select> selector in pure JS

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to make a personalized `:hover` for `<option>` elements in `<select>` selector by `mouseover` eventListener. But for some reasons `mouseover` does not fired when the mouse has been on the `option` element.

```js
    var selectOne = document.querySelector('.select__first');
    var selectTwo = document.querySelector('.select__second');

    for (var key in selectOne) {
      if (key % 2 == 0)
        selectOne[key].classList.add('select__option-blue');
    }

    for (var key in selectTwo) {
      if (key % 2 == 0)
        selectTwo[key].classList.add('select__option-blue');
    }
 
    function onMouseOver(e) {

      var target = event.target;

      var options = event.target.closest('option');
      if (!options) return;
      console.log(options);
    }

    document.addEventListener( 'mouseover', onMouseOver);
```

```css
    .select__element > p, span {
      display: inline-block;
    }

    .select {
        -webkit-appearance: listbox;
        cursor:  pointer;
    }

    .select__option-blue {
      background-color: lightblue;
    }

    option {
      cursor:  pointer;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style type="text/css">



  </style>
</head>

<body>

 <div class="select-row">
    <div class="select__element">
      <p>The last element: </p><span class="select__element-last"></span>
    </div>
    <select class="select select__first">
      <option value="birds" hidden>Select an element...</option>
      <option value="birds">One</option>
      <option value="fishes">Two</option>
      <option value="animals">Three</option>
      <option value="dino">Four</option>
      <option value="simplest">Five</option>
    </select>

    <select class="select select__second">
      <option value="birds" hidden>Select an element...</option>
      <option value="ploto">One</option>
      <option value="trava">Two</option>
      <option value="vseyad">Three</option>
    </select>
  </div>

  <script>



  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: My post is not about jQuery. I need pure JavaScript way

Comment: You can put that comment as part of the question (edit question). If you want to customize options in a select then it's best to make a custom select and not use the default so it shows up the exact same for all browsers. Best not to mess around with selects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, yes, the situation around `option` is a very sad. :(... As say @Veehmot - we cannot bind **mouseevents** on `option` elements of selector `select` normaly in pure JS.

But! In view of the fact that **I did not find any clear information on stackoverflow about what exactly can be done to stylize `options` and `select` selector on pure JavaScript**, I want to share my success in this direction and give the community 2 ways of solving this problem based on pure JavaScript.

I found a really **two working ways** for coders, who also like me will face the necessity of styling `option` and `select` on pure JavaScript without the use of frameworks (jQuery, etc.)

1. The first way (not direct and harder) is to make the `select` element with `options` in the form of `<div>` selector with `<buttons>` or `<li>` list inside. The introdusing of how it work you can see on my CodePen project-page below:

https://codepen.io/Sviatoslav_FrontEnd/pen/PQbBYQ

2. The second way is to connect one interesting JS library, created for `options` and `select` styling. This is really what we want, and it base on pure JavaScript with CSS. BUT! I want to admit, that this script is not mine. I found it on the open-source blog resource. So I'm not responsible for its support or help in setting up. All at your own peril and risk. 
   I place here a link to this JS library and support files solely to help the same as I - lovers a pure javascript.

Link: https://di-grand.com/blog?download=1&kccpid=3338&kcccount=https://di-grand.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/select.rar

Answer (score 2):

Apparently, [Chrome doesn't support mouse events](https://productforums.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!topic/chrome/p-k4hEDmxI0;context-place=topicsearchin/chrome/onMouseOver$20option) on `option` elements, unless you specify the `size` attribute to the `select` element.

- [Mouse over option in select tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8342048/mouse-over-option-in-select-tag)
- [jQuery-Select list option hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9143924/jquery-select-list-option-hover)
- [onMouseMove doesn't fire over <option> element in Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8902405/onmousemove-doesnt-fire-over-option-element-in-chrome)