# Mouseover event not fired on <select> options list item hovers

Tags: javascript, browser

I don't see any mouseover events from the `<select>` tag's options list. For example on this page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select I can add an event listener `document.addEventListener('mouseover', console.log)` and I will see all other mouseover events except as soon as I am hovering on the options list.

Any ideas on why a mouseover event isn't fired here? I am aware that I can listen for a `change` event on successful selection by user, just baffled why the mouseover event isn't being fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chrome doesn't support mouse events on option elements.

Check this answer out
https://stackoverflow.com/a/48668859/8474551

Comment: Oh wow! This is surely a very strange thing. Also been open for over 10 years now haha