# How to get event when user hovers over option to select

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I want to get an event when a user hovers over a select option.
I expected onMouseOver or onDragOver props on the option component to give me an event here, but they only work on the parent select component.

Here is a cut down example:

```
<select
  id="inputPath"
  value={selected.input_path}
  className="form-control"
>
  {nodes.map((node, i) => {
    return [
      <option
        onMouseOver={(e) => console.log('Nothing!', e)}
        key={`select-input-input-${i}`}
        value={`${toLower(node.text)}/input/`}
      >{`${toLower(node.text)}/input/`}</option>
    ];
  })}
</select>
```

Comment: A thread about `mouseover` on `<option>` in JS: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48668375/mouse-listeners-and-select-option-in-javascript-mouseover-eventlistener-does-no

Answer (score 0):

The onMouseOver event should work on the option element, but it might not be triggering because the option element is inside the select element, which might be capturing the event first.

One way to work around this is to use the onMouseMove event on the select element to detect when the mouse is over one of the options. Here's an example:

```
<select
  id="inputPath"
  value={selected.input_path}
  className="form-control"
  onMouseMove={(e) => {
    const target = e.target;
    const selectedOption = target.options[target.selectedIndex];
    if (selectedOption && selectedOption !== e.currentTarget) {
      console.log('Hovering over option:', selectedOption.value);
    }
  }}
>
  {nodes.map((node, i) => {
    return (
      <option
        key={`select-input-input-${i}`}
        value={`${toLower(node.text)}/input/`}
      >
        {`${toLower(node.text)}/input/`}
      </option>
    );
  })}
</select>
```